# Simple deform (twist) disappears when applied

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am trying to model a rope falling over a cube.  I created a path and added a soft body with a four-circle bevel object.  So, I have a four-tubed string that falls nicely.  Now I want to twist the four tubes to give a braided appearance.  I'm trying to follow the tutorial "Quick Noodle Physics in Blender Tutorial" by BlenderHD from 2015.  In that tutorial, he goes into edit mode, grabs the end vertex of the path and hits "Control T" to twist.  That didn't seem to do anything in Blender 3, nor did grabbing just one vertex and rotating in the long axis of the object with proportional editing.

So, I looked around and found the "Twist" modifier in "Simple Deform."  This seemed to work well, until the animation started.

So, here's the time zero without the twist -- just four circles turned into four cylinders by the magic of bevel:
[image]

Here it is after a few seconds of animation, with a reasonable droop:

[image]

So, now I add the simple deform twist, and get a nice braided appearance:

[image]

But when I animate it, it springs out like compressed razor wire:

[image]

So, I think to myself "Maybe I should apply it!"  I hit "Apply" for the deformation, and it disappears!  It goes back to the four parallel cylinder appearance.

There's an error message that appears,  but it disappears quickly, so I might not be reading it right. It says something like "This is applied to changed CV points, not beveled/tessellated vertices"

Rats. That's exactly want I want to do -- apply it to the beveled vertices.  What can I do to achieve this effect?

Thanks!

Comment: Modifiers are evaluated from top to bottom - try moving your deform modifier to the top. Applying a modifier is the same as moving it to top and then applying. The "error" you got was probably a warning about that: https://i.imgur.com/8ZtPmoJ.png *Applied modifier was not first, result may not be as expected*

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, moving it up makes it nonfunctional even for the twist at rest.

Comment: Addendum:  Interestingly, the "stretch" option of simple deform *does* apply, but twist, bend, and taper do not...  I suspect it's the same issue -- the deformation is being applied to the path, but not the bevel.

Comment: If the *Simple Deform* modifier is below *Soft Body* modifier, it means the physics simulation is played on the base mesh, and only then the modifier changes it. So if you apply the *Simple Deform* modifier, the physics simulation needs to be reevaluated for the new mesh.

Comment: Yeah.  I'm thinking that this Simple Deform thing isn't the right solution.  I'm hoping that there's another way to do it, but I don't know what it is.